# In any group of 17 people, where each person knows 4 others, you can find 2 people, which don't know each other and have no common friends.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a problem with proof of this (graph theory):

> In any group of 17 people, where each person knows exactly 4 people, you can 
>   find 2 people, which don't know each other and have no common friends.

I translated this to proving, that there exists a pair of vertices $\{v,w\}$, which aren't connected, that is, there isn't edge $(v,w)$ and for any other vertex $x$ from $V$ applies $(x, v) \veebar (x, w)$ or there is no edges between $x$ and $v$ and between $x$ and $w$, but then I am stuck.

I tried using Pigeonhole Principle, but I couldn't use it correctly, I think. I couldn't use Ramsey theory too.

Any help and hints would be appreciated.

I drew two examples of these graphs for help:
[image: 1st graph]
[image: ![secondGraph](https://i.imgur.com/a/Fnbmq7V.jpg)]

Comment: I do not think that this problem has a simple solution.  Any proof will most likely have to prove the non-existence of a [Moore graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph) with girth $5$ and degree $4$.  As far as I know, there is no non-algebraic proof.  See the pdf file in the link in my answer.

Comment: By the way, how did you draw your graphs?  Which software did you use?  They look very nice.

Comment: I used an online tool from [there](http://graphonline.ru/en/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G(V,E)$ be a $4$-regular simple graph on $17$ vertices.  We claim that there are two vertices $u,v\in V$ such that $u\neq v$, $u$ is not adjacent to $v$, and $u$ and $v$ do not have a common neighbor.  We prove by contradiction by assuming that, for any two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$, if $u$ is not adjacent to $v$, then $u$ and $v$ have a common neighbor.

Let $S$ denote all pairs $\big(\{u,v\},w\big)$ with $u,v,w\in V$ such that $u\neq v$, $\{u,v\}\notin E$, and $w$ is adjacent to both $u$ and $v$.  For each $w\in V$, $w$ has four neighbors.  Therefore, at most $\binom{4}{2}$ pairs of neighbors of $w$ are not adjacent.  This proves that
$$|S|\leq \binom{4}{2}\,|V|=6\,|V|=102\,.\tag{*}$$

Now, $|E|=\dfrac{4\cdot |V|}{2}=2\,|V|=34$ by the Handshake Lemma.  Thus, there are $$\binom{17}{2}-|E|=102$$ pairs of vertices $\{u,v\}$ that are not edges of $G$.  Each anti-edge pair $\{u,v\}$ produces at least one element of $S$, due to our hypothesis on $G$.  This proves that $$|S|\geq 102\,.\tag{#}$$

From (*) and (#), we must have $|S|=102$.  For (#) to be an equality, every anti-edge pair $\{u,v\}$ must have exactly one common neighbor $w\in V$.  Additionally, $G$ must be a triangle-free graph for (*) to become an equality.  This means $G$ is both triangle-free and quadrilateral-free.  Therefore, $G$ is a graph on $17=4^2+1$ vertices with [girth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(graph_theory)) $g\geq 5$ in which all vertices have degree $4$.  By the [Hoffman-Singleton Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hoffman-SingletonTheorem.html) (for a proof, see [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALAPP/Ullery.pdf)), if there exists an $r$-regular simple graph on $r^2+1$ vertices with girth at least $5$, then $r\in\{1,2,3,7,57\}$ (we know a partial converse, that is, for $r\in\{1,2,3,7\}$, there [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoffman%E2%80%93Singleton_graph) such a graph, but it is still a mystery for $r=57$, as you may guess, it is not easy to construct a graph on $57^2+1=3250$ vertices).  This yields the desired contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for including links to the additional material, I don't know the used theorem with girth. I will gladly learn it!

Comment: @ljaniec  This theorem has one of the most unexpected and beautiful proofs I know.  So, I am sure that it will benefit you greatly to learn such tricks.

Comment: @Batominovski - the H-S Theorem and the proof are awesome!  Every anti-edge $\{u,v\}$ having exactly 1 common neighbor, or equivalently, exactly 1 2-hop path, is such a natural combinatorial description, that it's hard to understand why we need an algebraic proof involving real eigenvalues.  Do you have any further insight into why there is no combinatorial proof?

Comment: @antkam I think the main difficulty is exactly how to combinatorially use the condition that there exists exactly one $2$-hop path between two nonadjacent nodes.  It is much easier to approach the problem using the adjacency matrix as you can see in the pdf file.  But when we start to use the adjacency matrix, our solution becomes at least partially algebraic.  And when you look at the result, the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $7$, and $57$ are very arbitrary, so it doesn't seem very likely to me that you can approach the problem from a purely combinatorial point of view.

Comment: Is this possible to solve with linear algebra aproach?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extremely tedious combinatorial proof...  :P  It works for this case but most likely cannot generalize.

**Lemma 1:** The following are taken from the first part of the answer by @Batominovski

- The graph $G$ is triangle-free and quadrilateral-free.
- If $(u,v)$ is not an edge then $u, v$ have exactly 1 common neighbor, which we will denote $N(u,v)$.

Let the nodes be $\{1, 2, ..., 17\}$.  The following tables show successive "forced" constructions of the adjacency matrix in "sparse format", i.e. a row "a: b, c, d, e" means there are edges a-b, a-c, a-d and a-e.

WOLOG we can pick node 1 and choose its 4 neighbors and their neighbors, to start:

```
 1:  2  3  4  5
 2:  1  6  7  8
 3:  1  9 10 11
 4:  1 12 13 14
 5:  1 15 16 17
```

Now consider nodes $\{6,7,...,17\}$ organized into 4 triplets $T_i: i \in \{2,3,4,5\}$ where each $T_i =$ the 3 nodes (among 6...17) connected to $i$.  E.g. $T_3 = \{9,10,11\}$.

**Lemma 2:** For $i \neq j: \{N(u,j): u \in T_i\} = T_j$, i.e. the function $N(.,j)$ is bijective from $T_i$ to $T_j$.

Proof: first of all $N(u,j) \in T_j$ because there is no other way to connect to $j$.  (The only other neighbor of $j$ is $1$ which does not connect to $u$.)  Next $u \neq u' \implies N(u,j) \neq N(u',j)$ because otherwise $(N(u,j), u, i, u', N(u',j))$ would be a quadrilateral.

Based on Lemma 2, WOLOG we can fill out the neighbors of every $u \in T_2$:

```
 6:  2  9 12 15
 7:  2 10 13 16
 8:  2 11 14 17
```

At this point we arrange the remaining nodes 9...17 and visualize them in a 3x3 grid:

```
   9   10   11  .. [3]
  12   13   14  .. [4]
  15   16   17  .. [5]
   :    :    :
  [6]  [7]  [8]
```

The 3 nodes of any given row have a common neighbor (3, 4 or 5, in []) and the 3 nodes of any given column also have a common neighbor (6, 7, 8, in []).

Node 13 still has 2 edges left.  It cannot connect to 12/14 on the same row (13-12/14-4-13 triangle) nor 10/16 on the same column.  The 2 edges must also connect to different columns (e.g. 13-9 & 13-15 would lead to 13-9-6-15-13 quadrilateral) and different rows.  WOLOG we connect 9-13 and 13-17.

```
   9   10   11  .. [3]
     \
  12   13   14  .. [4]
          \
  15   16   17  .. [5]
   :    :    :
  [6]  [7]  [8]
```

Now after connecting 9-13, node 9 has 1 edge left.  This cannot connect to 10/11 (same row as 9), nor 12/15 (same column), nor 16 (9-16-7-13-9 quad) nor 14 (9-14-4-13-9 quad), so it must connect to 17.  But this forms a triangle 9-13-17-9, a contradiction.

Whew...  and yuck.  :P

Comment: I assume that $N(u,v)$ is the common neighbor of an anti-edge $\{u,v\}$.  The proof looks correct to me.  Bravo!

Comment: yes, $N(u,v)$ is defined inside Lemma 1 to be what you said.

Comment: Oopps, I didn't see that for some reason.  :D

Comment: @antkam It was kind of thinking I had before, but I couldn't summarize it as well as you, thank you!

Comment: @ljaniec i know exactly what you mean.  it was really tedious until i found the 3x3 grid which helped me tremendously with the visualization of symmetries.  Batominovski's "no triangles and no quads" also provides a great rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I submitted a less than helpful response the first time. Here is my proof in this edit.

[image]

When all $17$ people within a group know $4$ people from the group, then there are $34$ friend pairings. 
In the above diagram, ensuring that everyone is at least a friend of a friend requires $52$ pairings "so far" just for persons $1$ through $5$. I have only worked the requirement for persons $1$ to $5$ because it already exceeds the requirement of knowing exactly $4$ others.

Every person in the group doesn’t personally know $12$ others in the group. But for there to be a possibility of sharing a friend with all $12$ others, every person’s $4$ friends must between them know all the other $12$.

In the diagram above, person $1$ personally knows $4$ others $(2,3,4,5)$. And between this $4$, they know all the other $12$ people ($6$ through $17$). But the same situation must exist for the friends of $1$, ($2,3,4$ and $5$). So, on the chart this requirement has been filled in where each set of $4$ friends for $2,3,4,5$ must know their corresponding other $12$. When this is done however, the number of friends for some of the people exceeds $4$. Not only that, but ensuring everyone is a least a friend of a friend hasn't been done for all $17$ in the group.

These are the $5$ acquaintance pairings so far:

$17 (8,11,12,13,14); 12 (6,7,8,10,17); 7(9,12,13,14,15)$

$16 (8,9,10,11,14); 11 (6,13,15,16,17); 6 (9,10,11,12,15)$

$15 (6,7,8,11,14); 10 (6,12,13,14,16)$

$14 (7,10,15,16,17); 9 (6,7,8,13,16)$

$13 (7,9,10,11,17); 8 (9,12,15,16,17)$

Therefore, for all unacquainted people to share a common friend, the unacquainted people have to know more than $4$ people. Hence with each person only knowing $4$ others, there will always be at least two people who don’t know each other and do not share a common friend.

A follow up question could be, what is the least number of  acquaintances each person must have to ensure that everyone is at least a friend of a friend?

[image]

Comment: Down vote, what am I missing?

Comment: This is an example, not a proof.

Comment: @helper Got it, revised my answer to relay this. A counter example would disprove the theory.

Comment: But it's still not an answer, the OP is asking for help *proving* this.

Comment: It is correct that 6,7,8 (who each knows 3) collectively have to know 9-17, but there is no reason to link 6 with 9-11.  in fact, since 6 must be only 2-hops from 2,4,5, this means 6 must link with exactly 1 of 9-11, 1 of 12-14 and 1 of 15-17.  suppose WOLOG 6 links with 9,12,15, then 6 must reach 10,11 via 12,15.  etc.  the challenge is to show that this is impossible to satisfy for everybody.

Comment: @antkam I see what you are saying, but even if you distribute 9-17 differently between 6,7,8, it still comes out that the number of connections exceeds 34 and hence everyone has to know more than 4 people. It doesn't matter if you switch around the groups of 3 on the outer edges of the diagram, there are 52 connections so far when only 34 are permissible with everyone knowing only 4 people.

Comment: "Even if you distribute 9-17 differently between 6,7,8, it still comes out that the number of connections exceeds 34" $\leftarrow$ my point is you havent proven this statement.  (Or at least: you have not explained your proof enough to convince me or @helper...)

Comment: @antkam helper wasn't commenting on this version. But, I see what you are saying. I've added a simpler example to my answer which may be easier to discuss. What is it specifically that needs to be added to prove that the 7 connections are insufficient to ensure everyone is at least a friend of a friend?

Comment: The 7 people example is easy because for any given person A, A can reach at most 2 +2 = 4 other people total in 2 hops, and 1+4 < 7.  The OP example is hard because for any given person A, it is possible to construct a graph G s.t. A can reach 4 + 12 = 16 other people in 2 hops, and 1+16=17.  While graph G works for A, the trick is to show there is no graph which works for everybody.

Comment: Back to your first Figure.  You have these links involving 6: (3, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15).  I agree that 6 has to link with 3, 9, 12 and 15.  Can you explain why 6 has to link with 10 & 11?  Why have you ruled out 2-hop paths e.g. 6-12-10 and 6-15-11?

Comment: What is obvious In the 7 people example is obvious after the second layer of my 1st figure. For all 17 to be connected by at most one other person (2 hops) it is possible to construct a map with any of the 17 at the center. Any 4 people can be chosen as direct contacts, this leaves 12 people to be filled in as acquaintances of those 4. The 17 are completely interchangeable at this point. When we extend the requirement that the 4 (2,3,4,5) have to be connected to another 12 people, it becomes obvious that there aren't enough connections (34 max) to achieve it, just like the 7 people example..

Comment: I was out of text, but if all 17 were connected by at most 2 hops, then it would be possible to construct a map identical to mine with 34 unique connections. Switching people around makes little difference, just shifts duplicates around,  which is a zero sum game.

Comment: Phil, I am not trying to be difficult :) but I really still dont understand what you're saying.  "when ... the 4 (2,3,4,5) have to be connected to another 12 people, it becomes obvious there aren't enough connections (34 max)" $\leftarrow$ how is that obvious?  Back in your 1st diagram, when you wrote **52** pairings, arent you double-counting?  E.g. link 6-9 appears twice in your diagram, but that's just 1 link, so I dont see where the number 52 comes from.

Comment: Please don't worry about it. Once you require a single person to know more than 4 people it contradicts being able to connect everyone to 16 others. There are 12 people needing to know 5 others to make those connections just for 5 of the 17. There are actually 40 connections, where 52 is the actual pairings on the chart with 12 of them being duplicates. 40 is 6 connections more than 34 involving the 12 people with 5 connections. I've gone further than this chart and it takes about 70 connections for all 17 people. Please don't worry, it's far from being a rigorous proof.

Comment: I think perhaps the best way for me to try one last time is to repeat my earlier question:  Suppose I agree with the original 16-node tree rooted at 1.  Then the leaves are 6-17.  Suppose I further agree that 6 needs to link with 9, 12, 15.  What FORCES 6 to link to 10 & 11?  I can see no IMMEDIATE/OBVIOUS reason why 6 must link with anybody else besides 3, 9, 12, 15.  If there is an immediate/obvious reason, then your proof is valid.

Comment: It doesn't, using the 7 people example, notice that there are six people with 3 connections and one person with 2. The solution has 7 different configurations whereby the person with only two connections has 7 different possibilities. For the configuration of the larger problem I'm working, person 1 only has 4 connections while 2,3,4,5 have 7 connections and 6 through 17 have between 8 and 11 connections. Nothing forces any particular pairing but when you swap a pairing all  it does is shift the numbers around without reducing the total. I'm still working it.